# How to replace the values ​different of the NaN value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to replace the values of the column begin different of Nan to the text "b".
Here my dataframe:

```
    begin                       
0   NaN                         
1   2019-10-21 07:39:28.052763 
2   NaN                         
3   NaN                         
4   2019-10-21 07:40:00.279654
```

the result should be like this

```
    New_begin                       
0   NaN                         
1   b 
2   NaN                         
3   NaN                         
4   b
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple `loc` assignment

```
df.loc[df.begin.notnull(), 'begin'] = 'b'
```

If you want a new column, just change `begin` to a new name (like `new_begin` in your example).

---

```
    begin
0   NaN
1   b
2   NaN
3   NaN
4   b
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`DataFrame.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) with [`isna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html):

```
df.begin.where(df.begin.isna(), 'b')

0    NaN
1      b
2    NaN
3    NaN
4      b
Name: begin, dtype: object
```